# Difficulty finding time complexity

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

I just solved a question on leetcode asking me to find combination of numbers summing to a given target. I just solved it but i am having difficulty in finding its time complexity. Please help.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution
{
    List<List<Integer>> result=new ArrayList();
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum2(int[] candidates, int target)
    {
        HashMap<List<Integer>,Integer> map=new HashMap();
        List<Integer> temp=new ArrayList();
        Arrays.sort(candidates);
        help(candidates,0,target,map,temp);
        return result;
    }
    private void help(int[] arr,int start,int target,HashMap<List<Integer>,Integer> storage,List<Integer> temp)
    {
        if(start>=arr.length)
            return;
        List<Integer> check=new ArrayList<>(temp);
        check.add(arr[start]);
        if(arr[start]==target)
        {

            if(storage.containsKey(check))
            {
                help(arr,start+1,target,storage,temp);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.add(arr[start]);
                result.add(temp);
                storage.put(temp,1);
                return;
            }
        }
        if(arr[start]>target)
        {
            return;
        }
        help(arr,start+1,target,storage,temp);
        help(arr,start+1,target-arr[start],storage,check);

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't go into the details of early terminations in your code, and how often they occur. But, double recursive calls with `n-1` elements is the "signature" of `O(2^N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1  `Arrays.sort(candidates)` normally `O(nlog(n))`. You also have 1 recursive with 2 calls, it should be `O(2^n)`. Therefore the worse case should be  `O(2^n)`

**(O1) An algorithm is said running constant time** regardless input size we call O(1).

```
    int getFirst(int[] arr) {
       return arr[0]; //O(1)
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap(){{
      put(1, 10);
    }};

    map.get(1); //O(1)
```

**O(n) If it run linear time.**

```
      int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += n[i];
        }
```

**O(logN) run in lograrithmic time**

Like binary search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

**O(n^2) 2 nest for loops**.
More nested iterations will result in O(n^3) O(n^4)...

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
      ...
  }
}
```

**O(2^n) it grow doubles with each addition to the input.**

```
public int fibo(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return fibo(n - 2) + fibo(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I also thought the same,but still wasnt sure about my answer :)